# SD Card Socket from Raspberry Pi 3 - Part Number

Tags: sd-card, sockets

Does anyone know the part number of the Micro SD Memory Card Socket Slot for the raspberry or where can I buy the same socket so to replace it?

[image]

Comment: Even if you found a replacement part, you will need exceptionally good soldering skills to replace the SD card slot. Especially without damaging any of the components near to it. Assuming your Pi is still under some kind of warranty I suggest returning it and seeing if you can get replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I find the right type of the connector after a long search on the digykey. Today I solder the new connector and Pi works fine.

Part Number: 1040310811
Manufacturer: Molex
http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex-llc/1040310811/WM6357CT-ND/2804769

Answer (score 0):

Digikey should have what you want:
molex 5040771891

http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/5040771891/WM9315CT-ND/3635129?WT.mc_id=IQ_7595_G_pla3635129&wt.srch=1&wt.medium=cpc&&gclid=CjwKEAiArvTFBRCLq5-7-MSJ0jMSJABHBvp02F5xYiSTVTz2NmNzmI8Hh7luvpHXfc0KjSP00s15ChoCZ_Tw_wcB

Comment: Perhaps you could expand your answer by explaining how the OP could actually carry out the operation of swapping out the SD card slots?

Comment: @ Darth Vader - The OP asked where they could get a new card slot; I provided that.  They didn't ask for a soldering lesson!  Based on the supplied image, I'd recommend a hot air rework station. Those are about $2k and not common for hobbyist to have.  Set temperature to 380C blow hot air on solder pads.  Use tweezers to lift damaged part off of board.